# show/hide fields based on value selected on another field while datagrid editing popup form

Tags: reactjs, devexpress, devextreme

I am a new bee to Devextreme , I created a popup editing form using data grid as mode as a popup. I want to show two fields on the fly. To be specific I have a field called as a status where the options are open and closed. If I select options as closed then I want to show two fields resolved on(datatype: date) and resolved by else just hide these two fields. Also, the fields should have prepopulated value such as approved on should have today's ate and should not be allowed to edit.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//You can use do this two method.
//1. when you have static condition
{ 
dataField: "Id",
caption: "ID", 
visible: (sessionStorage.getItem('isAdminUser') === "True") ? true,:false ,
}

//2.when you have dynamic condition. Data come from API the this method useful.
{
dataField: "Id",
caption: "ID", 
visible: (sessionStorage.getItem('isAdminUser') === "True") ? true,:false ,
   cellTemplate: function (container, options) {
    if (options.data.isAdminUser === "true") {
   }
}
```